# Sorting/comparison of doubles in C(++) not stable?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I've ran into a pretty wierd problem with doubles. I have a list of floating point numbers (double) that are sorted in decreasing order. Later in my program I find however that they are not exactly sorted anymore. For example:

```
0.65801139819
0.6545651031    <-- a
0.65456513001   <-- b
0.64422968678
```

The two numbers in the middle are flipped. One might think that this problem lies in the representations of the numbers, and they are just printed out wrong. But I compare each number with the previous one using the same operator I use to sort them - there is no conversion to base 10 or similar going on:

```
double last_pt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
  if (last_pt && last_pt < track[i]->Pt()) {
    cout << "ERROR: new value " << track[i]->Pt()
         << " is higher than previous value " << last_pt << endl;
  }
  last_pt = track[i]->Pt();
}
```

The values are compared during sorting by

```
bool moreThan(const Track& a, const Track& b) {
  return a.Pt() > b.Pt();
}
```

and I made sure that they are always double, and not converted to float. `Pt()` returns a double. There are no NaNs in the list, and I don't touch the list after sorting.

*Why is this, what's wrong with these numbers, and (how) can I sort the numbers so that they stay sorted?*

Comment: AFAIK, `float` is almost always 32 bytes whereas `double` is 64 bytes, on both architectures.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was assuming. So at least it's probably not that...

Comment: Could it be the sorting that is wrong? What do you use for sorting?

Comment: That is a typo :-). I removed that part of the question, since I think its too confusing and doesn't have much to do with the original problem.

Comment: @jdm, I don't see anything in your question that could suggest problems with "infamous machine epsilon" _or_ representation, looks more like an error in sorting or maybe the structure which `track[i]` is.

Comment: Please add a working program that reproduces your error

Comment: and what do you mean by "later in the program", are they sorted immediately after performing the sorting?

Comment: How do you sort those items? Please include both a declaration of class `Track` and the command that does sort the list.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Part of my problem is that this is in a huge messy legacy code base. I can't reproduce this in a simple program, sorry.

Comment: Note that in certain cases a comparison is done against the value still in some floating point register, and then when saved to memory, things are truncated to the precision of the value in memory. This can sometimes lead to the situation that a value compares differently with and without that optimization. The morale of this is: never use floats as keys in maps/sets or to sort data.

Comment: Why not print the doubles just prior to the sorting, stuff them into an array, then print them again after sorting, and post that small program here?

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you're not converting `double` to `float` at some time? Let us take a look at binary representation of these two numbers:

```
0 01111111110 0100111100100011001010000011110111010101101100010101
0 01111111110 0100111100100011001010010010010011111101011010001001
```

In `double` we've got 1 bit of sign, 11 bits of exponent and 53 bits of mantissa, while in `float` there's 1 bit of sign, 8 bit of exponent and 23 bits of mantissa. Notice that mantissa in both numbers are identical at their first 23 bits.

Depending on rounding method, there would be different behaviour. In case when bits >23 are just trimmed, these two numbers as `float` are identical:

```
0 011111110 01001111001000110010100 (trim: 00011110111010101101100010101)
0 011111110 01001111001000110010100 (trim: 10010010011111101011010001001)
```

Comment: Good observation! This should help me narrow it down. It's a huge code base with different modules connected by configuration scripts :-/. That's why I can't easily come up with a minimal example. I was 90% sure, but can't exclude the possibility.

Comment: Mind that unless the rounding mode has been changed explicitly it is round-to-nearest on x86 and x64 and the second number should have `1` in the lsb of the significand when converted to `float` (tested with `gcc` and `icc` with 32- and 64-bit Linux targets, as well as VS2010 with 32- and 64-bit targets, both with x87 and SSE instructions).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the return value of a function.  Floating point return
values are returned in a floating point register, which has higher
precision than a double.  When comparing two such values (e.g. `a.Pt() >
b.Pt()`), the compiler will call one of the functions, store the return
value in an unnamed temporary of type `double` (thus rounding the
results to `double`), then call the other function, and compare its
results (still in the floating point register, and not rounded to 
`double`) with the stored value.  This means that you can end up with
cases where `a.Pt() > b.Pt()` and `b.Pt() > a.Pt()`, or `a.Pt() >
a.Pt()`.  Which will cause `sort` to get more than a little confused.
(Formally, if we're talking about `std::sort` here, this results in
undefined behavior, and I've heard of cases where it did cause a core
dump.)

On the other hand, you say that `Pt()` "just returns a double field".
If `Pt()` does no calculation what so ever; if it's only:

```
double Pt() const { return someDouble; }
```

, then this shouldn't be an issue (provided `someDouble` has type
`double`).  The extended precision *can* represent all possible double
values exactly.

Comment: Interesting, your right about the Pt() function (http://1.usa.gov/MJbljh). I just checked again, and it does perform a calculation (however, I do expect to calls to Pt() do always return the same value).

Comment: This is only true for code that uses x87 FPU. The x64 ABI requires that floating-point values are passed in the XMM registers.

Comment: @jdm The calls themselves will always return the same value.  But that value has extended precision, and the compiler will "spill" one of the return values to memory, before making the second function call.  The value spilled to memory will be rounded to double precision.  The solution is to force both return values to double precision, by assigning them to a local variable, and comparing the local variables, e.g. `double t1 = a.Pt(); double t2 = b.Pt(); return t1 > t2;`.

Comment: Extended precision in return values would not cause the behavior reported by the asker. The two out-of-order floating-point values differ in double-precision, so they would differ in extended precision (and also differ if one were double, one were extended, and either was converted to the type of the other and then compared). This difference would cause them to be sorted correctly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The problem is comparing an extended precision value with the same value, but which has been stored in a double.  I've actually seen cases where the equivalent of `a.Pt() > a.Pt()` would return true.  Which is enough to confuse `std::sort`.

Comment: James Kanze, comparing extended-precision values to double-precision values would not explain the behavior reported by the asker. It can cause two values that would be equal in double precision to be reported as unequal. This can change the order into which the two values are sorted. However, they will end up next to each other anyway, so their order will be indistinguishable in the final results. When values that would be unequal in double precision are compared using a mix of extended and double precision, the correct result of comparison is returned, and the values are sorted correctly.

Comment: For example, consider four extended-precision numbers, a', b', c', d', in ascending order, and the same numbers converted to double precision, a, b, c, d, with the property that a < b = c < d. How will these numbers be sorted by a sort algorithm? When b and c might end up in either order, since comparing b to c reports they are equal but comparing b' to c, b to c', or b' to c' reports they are unequal. However, comparing either a or a' to any of b, b', c, or c' correctly reports that the former is less than the latter. Similarly, comparing any of b, b', c, or c' to either d or d' [continued]

Comment: correctly reports the former is less than the latter. So the sort cannot be mislead into sorting values that differ as doubles into the wrong order (d is never determined to be prior to b or c, b and c are never determined to be prior to a). Thus, extended precision does not explain the behavior reported by the asker.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the case I actually saw, the error caused `std::sort` to go out of bounds, crashing the program.  There is absolutely no guarantee as to what might happen.  (I've not studied your explication, for lack of time.  But I'm talking here about actually observed behavior, so any explication which says it's impossible must have a flaw somewhere.)

Comment: I do not assert the observed behavior is impossible, I assert the involvement of extended-precision values does not cause it. Therefore, there must be another cause.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the case in question, the problem was caused by the extended precision values.  Assigning the results to a `double`, and comparing those, fixed it.